# Percentage from SUM in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am building an application to see the progress of students.

I made a table active_projects. In here I got  : 
active_project_hours (the amount of hours they get from finishing)
active_project_percent (how far are they? as int, for example 50. This means 50%)

The problem is, I am fetching the data now like this :

```
"SELECT SUM(finished_project_hours) AS totalDone 
 FROM finished_projects 
 WHERE finished_project_user_id = {$_SESSION['user']['user_id']}";
```

But I want that if there for example is filled in :

```
active_project_hours = 10
active_project_progress = 20
```

that it does not sum the 10 hours, but 10 hours - 20 percent, so 8 hours

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand    Sum(hours * (100 - progress) / 100)

Comment: I am not getting your question, would update it and elaborate more...

Do you want solution in SQL or Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT SUM(active_project_hours * (1 - (active_project_progress/100)) AS timeRemaining
```